# Using LIKE between 2 columns in Big Query

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am having 2 tables i.e **tableA** and **tableB**.
I am fetching **colA from tableA** and **colB from tableB**. Now I want to join tableA and tableB on colA where colA is LIKE colB.

e.g if colB is having a value "*abcxyzijk*" and colA is having a value "*xyz*" then also it should join.
The join should **not be limited to colA = colB**.

I tried using the below code but it's giving only the records for which colA matches exactly with colB.

```
SELECT tableA.colA,  tableB.colB
FROM TableB tableB
INNER JOIN TableA tableA
ON tableB.colB LIKE tableA.colA
```

Is there any way of using LIKE between two columns in Big Query?

Answer (score 0):

You can instead use CROSS JOIN then filter the data using [HAVING](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#having_clause) and [REGEXP_CONTAINS](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_contains).

```
WITH Roster AS
 (SELECT 'Adams' as LastName, 'asdf' as SchoolID UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Buchanan', 'qwe' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Coolidge', 'zxc' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Davis', 'eryvbnqc' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'Eisenhower', 'pyimkmhjrty')

, TeamMascot AS
 (SELECT 'asdf' as SchoolID, 'Jaguars' as Mascot UNION ALL
  SELECT 'qwe', 'Knights' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'zxc', 'Lakers' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'vbn', 'Mustangs' UNION ALL
  SELECT 'rty', 'Cavs')

SELECT ros.LastName,ros.SchoolID, mas.SchoolID,mas.Mascot FROM Roster as ros
CROSS JOIN TeamMascot as mas
GROUP BY 1,2,3,4
HAVING REGEXP_CONTAINS(ros.SchoolID, mas.SchoolID)
```

Output:

[image]